# How to toggle on/off switch in Settings list

Tags: android, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

Using a keyboard but no mouse with an Android embedded system. I'm using keyboard navigation to set it up.

To turn on Wi-Fi I navigate to the Settings app, and highlight the Wi-Fi category in the list at left.

Pressing Enter causes the ON/OFF switch to highlight but not change state. Wi-Fi does not turn on.

Any ideas how to get a switch in a list item to toggle using the keyboard?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe spacebar or the 4 arrows?

Comment: Tried many variations of this type. Space bar moves the focus down (like paging through a web page). Arrows moved focus around, but I've found no way to hold focus on the Wi-Fi list entry and move the switch.